# Long JSON inside a column split into other columns

Tags: python, sql, sql-server

I have some SQL Server tables, where some of the columns have JSON inside them. I want to split those into new columns on the same table or maybe even another table with the respective unique ID.

My main problem is that the JSON has more than one group of values, an example:

```
[
   {
      "anexos":[
     
      ],
      "_id":{
         "$oid":"6047b19feada3700085241d7"
      },
      "created_at":"09/03/2021 14:34:22",
      "from":{
         "nome":"-",
         "id":"-"
      },
      "nota":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
   },
   {
      "anexos":[
      ],
      "_id":{
         "$oid":"6048dc8c26ac7f0008f3fd9f"
      },
      "created_at":"10/03/2021 11:49:48",
      "from":{
         "nome":"-",
         "id":"-"
      },
      "nota":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
   }
]
```

I tried to use OPENJSON but with little success, because it only returns the first value inside each JSON (or it seems like), follows:

```
SELECT
    t._id
FROM myTable as t
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(t.myColumn)
  WITH (_id decimal(20,11)) AS j;
```

I'm also willing to do this on SQL or Python (something inside pandas like json_normalize), which one will be more suitable?

Desirable output would be:

| global_id | _id.$oid | created_at | from.nome | from.id | nota |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 6047b19feada3700085241d7 | 09/03/2021 14:34:22 | ... | etc | etc |
| 1 | 6048dc8c26ac7f0008f3fd9f | 10/03/2021 11:49:48 | ... | etc | etc |

Comment: If there are more than one per row you would need to (or I should say the best approach) would be to create a child table with that joins to these extra records.  A one to many relationship.  Only other option would be to create multiple columns in same table for _id1, _id2 and so on for each one, but if you dont know how many there could be this would not work (and this is not the best way anyway and is not suggested but if you cant create a child table this would be the only really other way).

Comment: Please show the exact output you want for the given input.  For example, you don't have a scalar value `$._id`, you have `$[]._id.$oid` and even then it looks more like a GUID rather than a decimal.  Please read the following: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Comment: `OPEN_JSON` should for you, you just need to properly define your types and your paths. [Example on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/kutpgDHI)

Comment: `OPENJSON()` is only returning one value for you because that's all you're asking it to return. If you want more values you need to tell it which ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`OPENJSON()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql) can return multiple values, you just need to supply it with the appropriate parameter definitions and JSON query paths, e.g.:

```sql
SELECT
  t.global_id,
  j.*
FROM myTable as t
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(t.myColumn) WITH (
  [_id.$oid] varchar(24) '$._id."$oid"',
  created_at varchar(19),
  [from.nome] varchar(50) '$.from.nome',
  [from.id] varchar(50) '$.from.id',
  nota varchar(50)
) AS j;
```

Which returns the output:

| global_id | _id.$oid | created_at | from.nome | from.id | nota |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 6047b19feada3700085241d7 | 09/03/2021 14:34:22 | - | - | xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx |
| 1 | 6048dc8c26ac7f0008f3fd9f | 10/03/2021 11:49:48 | - | - | xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx |